# How to return function value with optional argument?

Tags: java, option-type

`subjectInfo` has optional `subjectName`, and using get directly on optional is code smell, and to use optional if present I have to create final variable in which I collect the result and finally return which I am trying to avoid, is there a better way to do it?

```
public String homework() { 
//If then else conditions based on different criteria

if (isValidSyllabusAndClass()) {
    return something;
} else {
    return myHomework.writeThesis(
               subjectInfo.getSubjectName().get(),
               syllabusAndClass.getSyllabus(),
               syllabusAndClass.getClass(),
           );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you explain it a bit more detail?

Comment: `and to use optional i have to create final Variable` why?

Comment: updated question , sorry for ambiguity

Comment: what if `SubjectName` is not present in `subjectInfo` @MikasaAckerman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Optional.map`.

If you want to avoid direct `Optional.get()`, you need to change the flow of your method, so the `Optional` does the branching, not an if statement.

```
return subjectInfo.getSubjectName().map(it -> myHomework.writeThesis(
           it,
           syllabusAndClass.getSyllabus(),
           syllabusAndClass.getClass(),
       )).orElseGet(() -> /*defaultCodeForNull*/)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `subjectInfo` is empty then you will get `NullPointerException` at this point

```
subjectInfo.getSubjectName().get()
```

So i will suggest to use `orElse(T other)` in `Optional`, if object is present it will return it, or else it will return the default values passed

> public T orElse(T other)
>
> Return the value if present, otherwise return other.

```
subjectInfo.getSubjectName().orElse("Default subject name")
```

Or simply you can check using `isPresent()`

```
else if(subjectInfo.getSubjectName.isPresent()) {
  return myHomework
       .writeThesis(subjectInfo.getSubjectName().get(),
                        syllabusAndClass.getSyllabus(),
                        syllabusAndClass.getClass(),
                        );
 }
```